# SQL Date Filtering with NOT NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    dbo.TABLE
LEFT JOIN
    table_insp insp ON TABLE.FORM_NO = insp.FORM_no
WHERE 
    (O_NMBR IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (O_DRCTN IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (O_INCHES IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (o_comments IS NOT NULL)
    AND insp.COMPLETED_DATE >= '10-01-2018'
```

The date filtering is not working. If I take out all of the IS NOT NULL, it works fine. How do I have the IS NOT NULLs and the date filtering work together, and why is it behaving like that?

Answer (score 1):

Add `()` in `OR`

```
SELECT * from dbo.TABLE
left join table_insp insp on TABLE.FORM_NO =  insp.FORM_no
where (
(O_NMBR is not null) 
OR (O_DRCTN is not null) 
or (O_INCHES is not null) 
or (o_comments is not null)
)

and insp.COMPLETED_DATE >= '10-01-2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `OR` conditions with brackets:

```
SELECT * from dbo.TABLE 
left join table_insp insp on TABLE.FORM_NO =  insp.FORM_no
where ((O_NMBR is not null) 
        OR (O_DRCTN is not null) 
        or (O_INCHES is not null) 
        or (o_comments is not null))
and insp.COMPLETED_DATE >= '10-01-2018';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to add parenthesis like:

```
SELECT * from dbo.TABLE
left join table_insp insp on TABLE.FORM_NO =  insp.FORM_no
where (
        (O_NMBR is not null) 
        OR (O_DRCTN is not null) 
        or (O_INCHES is not null) 
        or (o_comments is not null)
      )
  and insp.COMPLETED_DATE >= '10-01-2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need parentheses around the `OR` conditions.  I would also recommend using standard date formats:

```
where (O_NMBR is not null or O_DRCTN is not null or O_INCHES is not null or o_comments is not null
      ) and
      insp.COMPLETED_DATE >= '2018-10-01'
```